# DocuSign issue - data at the root level is invalid

Tags: docusignapi

We have been using DocuSign's SOAP based API calls to generate envelopes for our clients. We are having an issue while creating envelopes( and updating statuses of recipients)  with one of our client's DocuSign account. Whenever we create an envelope using their DocuSign account's credentials, the envelope gets created but we are not able to get the envelope ID and the status of the envelope. We are getting the following error:
"There is a problem with the XML that was received from the network."

The data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1. at System.Xml.XmlExceptionHelper.ThrowXmlException(XmlDictionaryReader reader, String res, String arg1, String arg2, String arg3) at System.Xml.XmlUTF8TextReader.Read() at System.Xml.XmlBaseReader.IsStartElement() at System.Xml.XmlBaseReader.IsStartElement(XmlDictionaryString localName, XmlDictionaryString namespaceUri) at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ReceivedMessage.ReadStartEnvelope(XmlDictionaryReader reader) at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedMessage..ctor(IBufferedMessageData messageData, RecycledMessageState recycledMessageState, Boolean[] understoodHeaders, Boolean understoodHeadersModified) at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TextMessageEncoderFactory.TextMessageEncoder.ReadMessage(ArraySegment`1 buffer, BufferManager bufferManager, String contentType) at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.DecodeBufferedMessage(ArraySegment`1 buffer, Stream inputStream)The data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1."

We are having same issues when we parse the DocuSign connect updates that we receive from this client's DocuSign account.

We also have tried creating the same envelope using another DocuSign account credentials and everything worked fine.

How do we resolve this issue?Is there anything wrong with this client's DocuSign account?

Comment: From a troubleshooting perspective, have you examined the received XML payload and parsed it through an XML validator to narrow down the potential XML formatting error ?

Comment: Yes. The XML is valid.

Answer (score 0):

I finally resolved the issue.
The error was misleading since there was nothing wrong with XML.

While making a SOAP based API call, I had set up a service reference to "na2.docusign.com" domain while our client's DocuSign account was residing in "www.DocuSign.com" domain.
Once I corrected the service reference, everything was working fine.

In the past, if I had set up the service reference incorrectly, I used to get "Invalid username/password" error. In case you are getting "Invalid username/password" error and your username and password for the DocuSign account are correct, please check the service reference and domain.